# Get smallest number in character string

Tags: r, string

I  have a data frame consisting of columns that capture different events. Respondents fill in the ages they experience those events. For any given event which they have experienced multiple times, they separate the age experienced with a semi-colon (e.g. if they experience it at 5, 6, 7 years old, they will input 5; 6; 7 in that particular column). For events that they have not experienced, respondents leave it with a blank.

As there are more than twenty columns, I concatenated all the columns together into 1 single column, resulting in a character column. I want to extract the smallest number in that character string. I am unable to force the columns into a numeric data type as some events will be experienced by respondents multiple times and be interpreted by R as a character string (e.g. "5; 6; 7")

My data looks something like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("001", "002", "003", "004"),
             concatenated = c("NA_NA_NA_NA_5; 6_NA_4_NA_NA_NA",
                              "3_3_NA_NA_NA_3; 4; 5; 6_NA_NA_NA_NA",
                              "NA_5_4_2_NA_NA_NA_NA_6; 7; 8; 9; 10_NA",
                              "NA_NA_11_12_11_NA_4; 5; 6_NA_NA_9"))

df$concatenated <- as.character(df$concatenated)
```

The end result I am trying to get is the following:

```
ID                           concatenated smallest_number
1 001         NA_NA_NA_NA_5; 6_NA_4_NA_NA_NA               4
2 002    3_3_NA_NA_NA_3; 4; 5; 6_NA_NA_NA_NA               3
3 003 NA_5_4_2_NA_NA_NA_NA_6; 7; 8; 9; 10_NA               2
4 004      NA_NA_11_12_11_NA_4; 5; 6_NA_NA_9               4
```

Thanks! Much appreciated!

Comment: It would be easier to find the minimum before pasting all the columns together to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your data is structured like:

```
DF <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,
                 age = c("5", "5;6;7", "20;15;12", "2;4"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You could use `strsplit` to split out each age as a number, then take the minimum in the usual way:

```
DF$min_age <- vapply(strsplit(DF$age, split = "[^0-9]"),
                     function(x) min(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE),
                     double(1))
```

If numbers sometimes don't appear, just exclude those rows

```
i <- grep("[0-9]", DF$age)  # rows with numbers somewhere
DF$min_age <- NA_character_
DF$min_age[i] <- vapply(strsplit(DF$age[i], split = "[^0-9]"),
                        function(x) min(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE),
                        double(1))
```

Comment: the above only works for one "age" column. I need to find the smallest age across all columns, with some columns having multiple age responses separated by semi-colon while the majority of columns are blank.

Comment: Do you want to know how to extract the age from your concatenated column, or the individual original columns? See my edit for the concatenated version.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. There are plenty of warning messages though: In min(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf. Is this a cause for concern? Thanks!

Comment: This suggests there are no numbers in that particular row. The 'minimum age' in that case will be positive infinity, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to change the positive infinity to NA? Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse` and `splitstackshape` you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(temp = gsub(";", "_", concatenated),
        temp = gsub(" ", "", temp)) %>%
 cSplit("temp", sep = "_") %>%
 gather(var, val, -c(concatenated, ID)) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(res = min(val, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 select(ID, concatenated, res)

  ID    concatenated                             res
  <fct> <chr>                                  <dbl>
1 001   NA_NA_NA_NA_5; 6_NA_4_NA_NA_NA            4.
2 002   3_3_NA_NA_NA_3; 4; 5; 6_NA_NA_NA_NA       3.
3 003   NA_5_4_2_NA_NA_NA_NA_6; 7; 8; 9; 10_NA    2.
4 004   NA_NA_11_12_11_NA_4; 5; 6_NA_NA_9         4.
```

First, it replaces `;` with `_` and splits the "concatenated" column according `_`. Second, it transforms the data from wide to long format and groups by "ID" column. Finally, it assess the minimum value and returns the data back to wide format.

Or with just `tidyverse`:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(temp = gsub(";", "_", concatenated),
        temp = gsub(" ", "", temp),
        temp = strsplit(temp, "_")) %>%
 unnest(temp) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric) %>%
 mutate(res = min(temp, na.rm = TRUE),
        rowid = row_number()) %>%
 spread(rowid, temp) %>%
 select(ID, concatenated , res)

  ID    concatenated                             res
  <fct> <fct>                                  <dbl>
1 001   NA_NA_NA_NA_5; 6_NA_4_NA_NA_NA            4.
2 002   3_3_NA_NA_NA_3; 4; 5; 6_NA_NA_NA_NA       3.
3 003   NA_5_4_2_NA_NA_NA_NA_6; 7; 8; 9; 10_NA    2.
4 004   NA_NA_11_12_11_NA_4; 5; 6_NA_NA_9         4.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can modify the elements with `gsub` to have a single underscore separated string for each item, and then use `scan` and `min` on them.

```
df$smallest_number <- sapply(df$concatenated, function(x){
  min(scan(text=gsub("; ","_",x), what = numeric(), sep="_"),na.rm=TRUE)})
df
#    ID                           concatenated smallest_number
# 1 001         NA_NA_NA_NA_5; 6_NA_4_NA_NA_NA               4
# 2 002    3_3_NA_NA_NA_3; 4; 5; 6_NA_NA_NA_NA               3
# 3 003 NA_5_4_2_NA_NA_NA_NA_6; 7; 8; 9; 10_NA               2
# 4 004      NA_NA_11_12_11_NA_4; 5; 6_NA_NA_9               4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
df$smallest_number <- sapply(
  str_extract_all(df$concatenated, "[0-9]+"),
  function(x) min(as.integer(x))
)
df
   ID                           concatenated smallest_number
1 001         NA_NA_NA_NA_5; 6_NA_4_NA_NA_NA               4
2 002    3_3_NA_NA_NA_3; 4; 5; 6_NA_NA_NA_NA               3
3 003 NA_5_4_2_NA_NA_NA_NA_6; 7; 8; 9; 10_NA               2
4 004      NA_NA_11_12_11_NA_4; 5; 6_NA_NA_9               4
```